# Simulate a memory space in C#

Tags: c#, memory, byte, simulation

I want to simulate a flash memory architecture in C#. More specifically the architecture looks like the following:

- Flash memory is a collection of blocks
- 1 block = 128 sectors
- a sector is composed of a data area and spare area
- data area = 8 kB
- spare area = 16 B

I wanted to represent this in a struct or in a class but the problem is I don't know how to represent a certain amount of memory space in the code. I can't use int or char arrays since I don't know what is to be stored in that memory space.... I am not very sure but I think I can represent it using byte datatype....

Comment: How about a byte array `byte[]`?

Comment: A disk is not the same as a memory space. You'll have to think about the functionality, like how access works.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it sounds like you want a byte array. For example:

```
 public sealed class Block
 {
     private readonly Sector[] sectors = new Sector[128];

     public Sector this[int index] { get { return sectors[index]; } }
 }

 public sealed class Sector
 {
     private readonly byte[] data = new byte[8 * 1024];

     public byte this[int index]
     {
         get { return data[index]; }
         set { data[index] = value; }
     }
 }
```

(You can model the "spare" area as well if you want - it's not clear whether you really need to though.)

That's only allowing single-byte-at-a-time access - you may well want to have `GetData` and `SetData` methods on `Block` which read/write chunks of data at a time. Hopefully this will get you started though.

Comment: Personally, I would just declare the entire range as `byte[]`, then go unsafe and use structs for Sector and Block. These can then be easily mapped, similar to what is usually done in embedded environments. You could even just `stackalloc` the entire space needed to a `byte*`.

Comment: @leppie: It depends what the aim is, I guess. I'd personally not use unsafe code without good reason to, but it does depend on the purpose.